# Eclipse IDE синхронизация файлов с сервером

Tags: eclipse

Какой самый удобный вариант для синхронизации файлов с сервером в Eclipse? Попробовал встроенный инструмент, не понравился так как синхронизация работает в обе стороны, мне это не оч подходит, удалил каким то образом файл на серваке и на локалке исчез.